# Google Search is URL Encoded

Tags: macos, safari

When I try to use the top bar in Safari to Google something, it sometimes URL-encodes the entry.

[image]

[image]

Safari treats this as a URL and gives an error, since this is not a valid URL. If I ignore this it will stop after some time, or I can restart Safari and it fixes the issue.

I started using MacOS in High Sierra and now use Mojave, both have had this issue.

Since I am new(ish) to MacOS, maybe I am using some key-combo that changes 
to URL search instead of Google?

Below, are my specs. This also happened on my late 2016 MBP, previously.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be random, & yes, irritating. I haven't figured out any pattern in how/why it sometimes does it.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Are you on the latest Mojave? I can't duplicate your problem anywhere. Please describe your hardware. There must be something peculiar in your configuration because I literally have never had that happen. I'd love to help solve your problem.

Comment: @BillSmith, I am on the latest Mojave. I've updated the question with system specs, I appreciate the help!